# How do I get out of fullscreen mode in Chrome with a Mac keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, mac, fullscreen

Since <kbd>F11</kbd> is volume, you can't just press it. Also, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't work either.

Comment: Cmd+F11 should work.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! BTW, Cmd+F11 does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

<kbd>Fn</kbd> will enable the actual <kbd>F*</kbd> keys instead of the media keys that are normally active.